# Indefinite integral over PolyLog, Log and 1/x

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I connection with some formulas including the harmonic series I stumbled over this indefinite intergral which Mathematica resisted to solve

```
f = Integrate[1/x Log[x] PolyLog[2,1/(1+x)],x]
```

Whereas slight simplifications like these

```
f1 = Integrate[1/x PolyLog[2,1/(1+x)],x]
f2 = Integrate[Log[x] PolyLog[2,1/(1+x)],x]
f3 = Integrate[PolyLog[2,1/(1+x)],x]
```

work out fine.

Any helpful hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried applying e.g. [Landen transformations](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9408113) to your dilogarithms? I'll look at this in detail when I find the time to do so.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you, but no I didn't know this transformation before, and at a first glimpse, it lookes fairly complicated. I have found a simple solution myself.

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be found using a transformation of the variables to simplify the argument of the PolyLog function.

The integrand is

```
ix = (Log[x] PolyLog[2, 1/(1 + x)])/x;
```

And the antiderivative (solution of the integral) is

```
int = 1/12 (Log[x]^4 - 4 Log[x]^3 Log[x/(1 + x)] + 
     6 Log[x]^2 Log[x/(1 + x)]^2 - 
     12 Log[x] Log[1/(1 + x)] Log[x/(1 + x)]^2 - 
     6 Log[1/(1 + x)]^2 Log[x/(1 + x)]^2 - 4 Log[x] Log[x/(1 + x)]^3 + 
     14 Log[1/(1 + x)] Log[x/(1 + x)]^3 + Log[x/(1 + x)]^4 - 
     4 Log[x]^3 Log[1 + x] - 12 Log[x]^2 PolyLog[2, -x] + 
     6 PolyLog[2, 1/(1 + x)]^2 - 
     24 Log[x] Log[x/(1 + x)] PolyLog[2, x/(1 + x)] - 
     12 Log[1/(1 + x)] Log[x/(1 + x)] PolyLog[2, x/(1 + x)] + 
     30 Log[x/(1 + x)]^2 PolyLog[2, x/(1 + x)] + 6 PolyLog[2, x/(1 + x)]^2 + 
     6 PolyLog[2, 1/(
       1 + x)] (2 Log[x]^2 - 4 Log[x] Log[x/(1 + x)] + 3 Log[x/(1 + x)]^2 + 
        2 PolyLog[2, x/(1 + x)]) + 24 Log[x] PolyLog[3, -x] + 
     24 Log[x] PolyLog[3, 1/(1 + x)] + 
     12 Log[1/(1 + x)] PolyLog[3, 1/(1 + x)] - 
     24 Log[x/(1 + x)] PolyLog[3, 1/(1 + x)] + 
     24 Log[x] PolyLog[3, x/(1 + x)] + 
     24 Log[1/(1 + x)] PolyLog[3, x/(1 + x)] - 
     36 Log[x/(1 + x)] PolyLog[3, x/(1 + x)] - 24 PolyLog[4, -x] + 
     12 PolyLog[4, 1/(1 + x)] + 12 PolyLog[4, x/(1 + x)]);
```

verifying

```
Simplify[D[int, x], 0 < x < 1]

(* Out[83]= (Log[x] PolyLog[2, 1/(1 + x)])/x *)
```

*Derivation*

Letting

```
{x -> 1/t - 1, dx = -dt/t^2};
```

the integrand becomes

```
it = -1/t^2 (ix /. x -> 1/t - 1 

(* Out[77] = -(((Log[1 - t] - Log[t]) PolyLog[2, t])/((-1 + 1/t) t^2)) *)
```

Now the integral over `it` can be solved, and transforming back we have for the indefinite integral

```
Integrate[-(((Log[1 - t] - Log[t]) PolyLog[2, t])/((-1 + 1/t) t^2)), t];

% /. t -> 1/(1 + x);

Simplify[% == int]

(* Out[86]= True *)
```

Done.

*Comment*

It is surprising that Mathematica is not able to find this simple transformation of the integration variable.

Answer (score 0):

Consider function

```
g[x_,a_]=Integrate[x^a PolyLog[2,1/(1+x)],x]
```

It is expressed via lots of hyper-geometric functions. At least formally the desired integral is `D[g[x,a],a]/.a->-1`. But there is a singularity. One can try to take a limit `a->-1` Computer calculates for long without stop. Another way is to expand Series[g[x,a],{a,-1,1}] and take the coefficient of the (a+1) term. This gives the result but as a very large expression.

Comment: Thank you. Good idea in priciple but not really useful here because of the rather poor performance of Mathemtica with Hypergeometric functions.